# Filter DropDown by text is not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am binding dropdown value using ng-repeat. In db I am storing value of the dropdown. when displaying I am showing text. I want to filter the dropdown using text

```
<select id="UOMid" class="form-control" typeof="text" ng-model="UOMSelect" required name="UOMType" form="Floorform" ng-change="verifySKUDuplicate()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="UOMTypeInformation in UOMTypeInformations | filter: UOMType " value="{{UOMTypeInformation.UOMTypeId}}">{{UOMTypeInformation.UOMType}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried to filter the dropdown data using the name. But it is not working

```
<option ng-repeat="UOMTypeInformation in UOMTypeInformations | filter: UOMType " value="{{UOMTypeInformation.UOMTypeId}}">{{UOMTypeInformation.UOMType}}</option>`     `
```

Comment: If your filter name is 'UOMType' just type it after '|' char. Dont type filter.

Comment: yeah I tried that way, it is not working

Comment: Can you share 'UOMType' filter code ?

Comment: <input type="text" id="UOMID" ng-model="Manage_SKU_Master.UOMType" placeholder="search" class="searchbox" />